# How to dynamically create component tags for mapped items

Tags: reactjs

There are list of react Icons that i'm trying to dynamically map through and then attach component tags to them.

```
import { FaBraille , FaDiceD20 } from 'react-icons/fa';



render(){
  return (
    <div> 
     {this.state.lists.map((detail, index) =>  
        React.createElement(detail.icons)
      }
    </div> 
 )}
```

I tried several different ways like this:

```
      React.createElement(window[detail.icons], {});
```

and even this:

```
          React.createElement(`${detail.icons}`)
```

Still the component tag is not getting created. Instead it displays `React.createElement(FaBraille)` on the screen but expected is like this: `<FaBraille />`

Is it possible to create component tags dynamically?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean with *"Instead it displays ... on the screen"*? `React.createElement(detail.icons)` is executed at runtime, I fail to see how it is possible to "display" either of those "on the screen". EIther, what is the value of `detail.icons`? If it is a string, then you need to build a map from `string => component` first. E.g. `const icons = {FaBraille, FaDice20};` and `React.createElement(icons[detail.icons])`.

Comment: If I write `React.createElement(detail.icons)` then the element is not created. it shows this way on the screen: `React.createElement(FaBraille)`.  value of  detail.icons is `FaBraille`

Comment: I still don't know what that means. Are you saying you literally have the text `React.createElement(FaBraille)` showing up in (rendered) HTML? Something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/m3hda6Lj/ If yes, then you are not showing the code you are actually using. *"value of detail.icons is FaBraille"* That still doesn't tell me the type of the value. Either way I think this is a duplicate.

Comment: I have added couple of pictures.

Comment: Well, that explains it. If you want to embed JavaScript within JSX, you have to put it within `{...}`, just like you do with the `...map(...)` call itself: `<div className="..."> ... {React.createElement(detail.icons)} ...</div>`. Note that this is different from your original example because that doesn't have JSX inside `.map` callback. Which is exactly what I meant when I said *" you are not showing the code you are actually using"*: Your original example cannot produce the result you see. But that will only solve part of the problem. See the duplicate for the other part of your problem.

Comment: I was able to solve this with switch case: `switch(detail.id) {
    case 1:
      return  <FaBraille />;
    default:
      return <FaDiceD20 />;
  }'